# Implementing comment section for each post in flutter with cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating instagram app clone in flutter with firebase at backend. It's a beginner level project so the coding and structure is basic.

I am stuck at adding comment section under each post. I'm using streambuilder to display data and trying to create a function in which with every image is on the feed screen would have a comment box which is connected to the current-image document in cloud-firestore.

Below is my code and images of database:

```
class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeedScreenState createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


  

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          "Platform",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.96,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontFamily: 'Yaldevi',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return ListView(
              children: documents.map((doc) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: doc['profileImage'] == null ?
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 16.6,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
                        ) :
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 16.6,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                doc['profileImage']
                            )
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                            doc['displayName'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.5,
                            )
                        ),
                        subtitle: doc['title'] !=null ?
                        Text(
                          doc['title'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12.5,
                          ),
                        ) :
                        Text(
                            "Some Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                        ),
                      ),
                      if(doc['photoURL'] != null) ... [
                        Container(
                          height: 400,
                          width: 400,
                          child: Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              doc['photoURL'],
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          )
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.mode_comment_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  CommentSection(),
                            ));
                          },

                        )

                      ] else if(doc['photoURL'] == null) ...[
                        Container(
                          height: 400,
                          width: 400,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              "assets/images/placeholder.png"
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 13.5 ),
                            child: Text( "@ " +
                                doc['displayName'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 13.5),
                              child: doc['decsription'] != null ?
                              Text( ":" +
                                  doc['decsription'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                              ) :
                              Text(
                                  "Some Descritiption",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
              )).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and here`s the comment screen code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class CommentSection extends StatefulWidget {
  // const CommentSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CommentSectionState createState() => _CommentSectionState();
}

class _CommentSectionState extends State<CommentSection> {
  var username = ' ';
  List photoURL = [];

  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String comments = ' ';




  sendComment() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    final name = user!.displayName;


    var res = await  userRef.where('userid', isEqualTo: user!.uid).get();



      _formKey.currentState!.save();

      var doc = userRef.doc('photoURL');
      doc.set({
        'comment' : comments,
      });



  }






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body:  Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                            child: TextFormField(
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Leave a Comment..",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )
                                ),
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  comments = value!;
                                }
                            ),
                          )

                        ],
                      )
                  ),

              ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: sendComment,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send,
                      color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  label: Text(
                    "Send"
                  ))
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: database pic*]

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: problem isn`t in the code,i embedded the code for better understanding, i`m asking for the method or function by which i can implement comment section with the displaying image, the comment should be add with the particular image document in firestore, like i tried creating a seperate collection for comment but the comment would be fetched for every image in database and i`m trying to save and reterive the comment data for particular image like we see and use in instagram!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really broad use-case, and honestly a bit too broad to answer on Stack Overflow. I recommend focusing on a more concrete, specific problem.

For example, you mention in your comment:

> I tried creating a separate collection for comment but the comment would be fetched for every image in database and I'm trying to save and retrieve the comment data for particular image

To allow reading only comments on a specific image, you'll need to associate each comment in the database with an image. The two most common approaches for this are:

1. Create a document for each image in a top-level collection, and then create a subcollection under that document for the comments on that specific image.
2. Create a single top-level comments collection, and store the ID of the image in each comment document.

Comment: okay gonna try!

Comment: first approacher worked!